# What is portal in PostgreSQL Frontend/Backend protocol?

Tags: postgresql

I am reading postgresql protocol documentation ([message formats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html) and [protocol flow](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html)).
There are several mentions of term portal in the docs, but there are no explanations.
What is it?

Answer (score 1):

The clearest answer is probably in the source code comments - https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/utils/portal.h.

> A portal is an abstraction which represents the execution state of
> a running or runnable query.  Portals support both SQL-level CURSORs
> and protocol-level portals.

So it's an abstraction that allows programmatic execution of a query. As a Java application developer, I've never really needed to know about them - that C library is an internal interface, and not sure if the concept is visible in any client side interfaces, for instance the way prepared statements are. If the concept **is** client facing I suspect it is used in code at a lower level than application code eg client libraries/drivers.

I came across them when looking at a Postgres extension (a library that can be loaded into the database and used to augment the built in functionality), and looking at that source can be quite helpful in making sense of how the portal is used - see https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/blob/fa978887b0277ccd22ef5332ebf3876780b64d5f/src/pg_cron.c#L2248